# Why Destroy Action is NOT being fired?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3 and trying to see why the Destroy action is not being fired! My html fired is defined as follows:

```
  <%= link_to "Delete", :action => "destroy", :id => article, :method => :delete, :confirm => "are u sure?" %>
```

And here is the ArticlesController:

```
def destroy

    @article = Article.find(params[:id]) 
    @article.destroy 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_url }
    end

  end
```

When I click on the "Delete" link it takes me to the show action. I am not sure why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `link_to` should be this:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", @article, :method => :delete, :confirm => "are u sure?" %>
```

This will generate the correct URL for your article and go to the `destroy` action.

Comment: The first argument to `link_to` is the text for the link, the second is the URL to the resource (or the resource itself, where Rails will determine the URL for it) and then the final arguments are options for `link_to` and then html options. Read the docs here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Answer (score 1):

Have you deleted the `javascripts` directory which resides in the `public` directory of your rails app?

If yes, create a new rails project and copy the `javascripts` directory in your actual project

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your application.js has included this line:

`//= require jquery_ujs`

That solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

That first line should be

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
```

Once you make this change, you won't be able to redirect to @article, since it will be gone; you'll probably need to replace that last line with redirect_to `articles_url`. The whole new method will be:

```
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id]) 
  @article.destroy 

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to articles_url}
  end
end
```

If you have trouble with stuff like this, try creating a scaffolded model with `rails generate scaffold Test` to see what the default options are.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the new to find but still it is not deleting the record.

Comment: Is it finding the article properly? I recommend running rails console and trying out the Article.find line, and seeing if you get anything back from the database.

Comment: Thanks! I just ran the console and it does return the record in the console. I am not sure why it is not deleting the record. The strange thing is that when I click on the delete link it takes me to show action.

Comment: In the article.rb model I also do not see the id field. But maybe that is part of the ActiveRecord::Base class and I do not have to declare it.

Comment: It'll take you to the show action until you change the redirect_to call at the end of the method. If you redirect to an object, it callsthe show action by default. Also, you're right that id is defined by active record... You can find it in schema.rb, if you like.

Comment: When you run destroy on the returned instance in the console, does it work? If so, just make sure changes are saved in the controller.

Comment: What do you mean changes are saved in the controller. Is @article.destroy not enough!

Comment: I just checked and I can delete from the console perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

It could also be this [Why are default javascript files required to create a destroy link in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837219/why-are-default-javascript-files-required-to-create-a-destroy-link-in-rails).